# URL hash :target on ajax element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a css animation that highlights a target element targeted by # in url.

```
a:target {animation:highlight 2s ease;}
```

However if the :target is loaded by ajax after the page loads, the animation won't show. Can I use javascript to force the element to :target state after it has loaded?

Comment: _“However if the :target is loaded by ajax after the page loads, the animation won't show.”_ - presumably because you _suppressed_ the actual change of the hash portion of the URL somehow? (Please show a proper [mre] with questions like this, so that we don’t have to _guess_ what you are actually doing.) If so, then explicitly _setting_ it might perhaps be enough already to fix the issue.

Comment: 1. Page is navigated to /page.html#P, on which the element with id=P doesn't exist
2. An automatic ajax call fetches a json, and create an element with id=P
3. Then I typed $('a:target') on console, it contains nothing

Comment: [mre] means, show a _proper_ example that illustrates your problem - so that people here have something they can experiment with and modify. Don’t expect us to create something we can test this with ourselves, based on a vague description delivered in a comment.